# TSQL - force update of persisted computed column

Tags: t-sql

I have a persisted computed column in one table with the value calculated using a user function. How can I force that column to be updated without updating any other column in that table?

UPDATE: So as it turns out, this will not work as I imagined it.

I wanted to have user function that contains sub-query in it, gets me some data and stores it in computed column. But SQL Server won't allow this...

It looks like I will have to do something similar with insert/update triggers.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: All the rules and limitations around which functions you're allowed to call as part of creating a persisted computed column would seem to preclude it ever returning a different value if its run again. So, what is the `UPDATE` meant to achieve? Could you create a small but complete script that demonstrates your situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you persist the value by adding the PERSISTED keyword, the value is both retained on insert and will be synchronized when the referenced column is updated.